# When i try to send email the app crashes

Tags: android

When i pressed a button the app needs to be take aal the info to the gmail or any mail app but it crashes.
this is what i used.

```
Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"youremail@yahoo.com"});          
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "message");
email.setType("message/rfc822");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));
```

Comment: Could you please post the logcat messages?

Answer (score 2):

Try this code. If there are no Apps on the device that can handle the intent, in your case `Intent.ACTION_SEND`, the App will crash.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("message/rfc822");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"recipient@example.com"});
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject of email");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "body of email");
try {
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "There are no email clients installed.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

Here the [repository](https://github.com/David-Hackro/ExamplesAndroid/tree/master/EnvioMails) with this code, and [here](http://www.mkyong.com/android/how-to-send-email-in-android/) a tutorial

```
private EditText to;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    to= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.to);
}   


public void Enviar(View view) {

    Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{to.getText().toString()});
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, new String[]{ to});
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_BCC, new String[]{to});
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, asunto.getText().toString());
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, cuerpo.getText().toString());

    //need this to prompts email client only
    email.setType("message/rfc822");

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));

}}


 //method get account the device
static String getEmail(Context context) {
AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(context);
Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccounts();
Account account = accounts[0];//getAccount(accountManager);

if (account == null) {
    return null;
} else {
    return account.name;
}
}
```

[image]

**Good Luck**

Answer (score 1):

Wrap `startActivity()` in `try/catch` to avoid crashes where there's no activity to handle your intent (you shall read the stacktrace (via LogCat) and you will see `ActivityNotFoundException` there)

```
Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"youremail@yahoo.com"});          
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "message");
email.setType("message/rfc822");

try {
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));
} catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();

     // show toast etc to the user
}
```